# Как решить эту задачу из Codewars?

Tags: java

[image: Условие]

Задача из Codewars, string incrementer
Как решить эту задачу, используя Java?

Comment: А какие у вас трудности?

Comment: @Lucy, а какой смысл в задании на английском языке в виде картинки?  Вроде бы не первый вопрос задаёте.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Проверяете, является ли входная строка `str` непустой и оканчивается ли на цифру (можно использовать методы класса `String`: `length(), isEmpty(), length(), charAt(int index)`, и `Character::isDigit`).
2. Если условие не выполняется, возвращаете исходную строку `str` с добавленной единицей: `str + "1"`.
3. Создаёте экземпляр `StringBuilder`, чтобы проще было менять символы внутри строки.
4. Идёте от конца строки, берёте значение цифрового символа (`Character::getNumericValue`), прибавляете 1 к символу в текущей позиции (с учётом остатка от деления на 10), обновляете символ в текущей позиции, проверяете наличие переноса в старший разряд.
5. Если есть перенос, а строка закончилась или не найден очередной цифровой символ, вставить `1` в текущую позицию (StringBuilder::insert).
6. Возвращаете строку, полученную из `StringBuilder`.

---

Реализация в коде не приводится в педагогических целях.